# volatile boolean assignment in rxjava source code

Tags: rx-java

I'm reading rxjava 1.0 source code and found the piece of [code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/test/java/rx/observers/SerializedObserverTest.java#L753)

```
volatile boolean onError;

try {
    onError = false;
} finally { ... }
```

What is the sense of try/catch?

Comment: I think you better post this question on RxJava's GitHub page as an issue to address it directly to lib developers.

Comment: Hi. I have read their page and they qualified such questions as more suitable for stackoverflow. Thank you though. If there were not answers I will try on github.